# What is the default interpretation for unprefixed numbers in the NoWarn prop of MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, warnings

So, imagine this project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <NoWarn>75</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here, how does MSBuild interpret 75?

I imagine one of the following:

1. It defaults to C# compiler warnings
2. It figures out the lang of the project and defaults to warnings in that lang (so CS0075 or FS0075 or BC0075)

The docs somewhat [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#nowarn) the first suggestion but I cannot find any explicit mention, so just want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NoWarn` property is documented in "[Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022)" which states that it:

> ... corresponds to the /nowarn switch of the compilers.

I confirmed that the `$(NoWarn)` property is passed to the `DisabledWarnings` parameter of the [Csc task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/csc-task?view=vs-2022), the task that wraps the C# compiler. From the docs, the `DisabledWarnings` parameter is used for the `-nowarn` switch.

Searching the legacy and sdk style project support files for C#, error codes for other tools are added to the property with their respective prefixes. There is no evidence of any language mapping. I suspect the complete list is passed to each tool and, since it is a filter list, error codes that don't pertain to the given tool are just never matched when filtering.